# why if $f$ is a bounded linear functional then ker $f$ is a closed subspace of the hilbert space $H$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

The book said: "if $f$ is a bounded linear functional then ker $f$ is a closed subspace of the Hilbert space $H$."

But I do not know why, could anyone clarify this for me please?

Comment: the kernel is the preimage of $\{0\}$ which is a closed set.

Comment: To be honest, that^ was a total guess. I know nothing about functional analysis. Please apply a grain of salt.

Comment: If so then every ker $f$ is closed ..... so what is the importance of $f$ being bounded and linear? @Randall

Comment: Bounded linear functionals are continuous.

Comment: Then what ? @DavidMitra

Comment: Holy crap I was actually right?!?  (with an assist by @DavidMitra)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the field of scalars be denoted by $\Bbb K$, where $\Bbb K = \Bbb R$ or $\Bbb K = \Bbb C$.  Then taking $f:H \to \Bbb K$, since $f$ is bounded we have a positive real constant $\mu$ such that, for all $x \in H$,

$\vert f(x) \vert \le \mu \Vert x \Vert, \tag 1$

where $\Vert x \Vert = \langle x, x \rangle^{1/2}$ is the usual norm on $H$, induced by the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ on $H$.

Suppose $x_n \in H$ is a sequence of vectors in $\ker f$:

$f(x_n) = 0, \; \forall n \in \Bbb Z_+, \tag 2$

where $\Bbb Z_+ = \{m \in \Bbb Z \mid m > 0 \}$, and suppose that $x_n$ is Cauchy in $H$; this means that for every real $\epsilon > 0$ we can find $N \in \Bbb Z_+$ such that, for $i, j > N$,

$\Vert x_i - x_j \Vert < \epsilon; \tag 3$

since $H$ is Hilbert, the sequence $x_n$ converges to some $x \in H$; that is, for any positive $\epsilon$, taking $N$ suffiently large, we have,

$\Vert x - x_i \Vert < \epsilon, \tag 4$

provided $i > N$.  Then

$\vert f(x) \vert = \vert f(x) - f(x_i) \vert = \vert f(x - x_i) \vert \le \mu \Vert x - x_i \Vert < \mu \epsilon, \tag 5$

where we have used the linearity of $f$ to assert $f(x) - f(x_i) = f(x - x_i)$, and the assumption that $f(x_i) = 0$ to affirm $f(x) = f(x) - f(x_i)$.  Now since $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary positive real, (5) forces

$f(x) = 0; \tag 6$

thus $x \in \ker f$ and hence $\ker f$ is closed in $H$.

The above demonstration is essentially the same as arguing that the continuity (that is, the boundedness) of $f$ implies that the inverse image of the closed set $\{ 0 \} \subset \Bbb K$ is closed in $H$.

***Note:*** $H$ need merely be Banach, not necessarily Hilbert, for the above argument to fly; in that case $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is not generally induced by in inner product, but all else said above holds.  ***End of Note.***

Comment: Thank you so much for you detailed beautiful demonstration :)

Comment: @Idonotknow:  your most welcome; glad to help out.  And thanks for the "acceptance"!

Comment: Must ker $f$ be a proper subspace of $H$? or can it be the whole $H$?

Comment: @Idonotknow:  $\ker f$ is proper if $f \ne 0$; then $\exists v \in H \mid f(v) \ne 0$, so $v \notin \ker f$.  If no such $v$ exists, then $\ker f = H$, right?

Comment: yes right :) thanks alot .

Answer (score 0):

> **Hint:** Let $(X,d_1)$ and $(Y,d_2)$ be metric spaces. The map $f:X \to Y$ is continuous $\iff$ $f^{-1}(Z)\subset X $ is closed for each closed subset $ Z \subset Y$.

Comment: Could you explain it in details for me please? as this statement was used by the author in the book "Basic operator theory " in preparation for proving Riez representation theorem  and I did not understand it...... thanks in advance.

Comment: Where could I find the proof of your above hint?

Comment: Do you know the following result: "Let $(X,d_1)$ and $(Y,d_2)$ be metric spaces. The map $f:X \to Y$ is continuous $\iff$ $f^{-1}(Z)\subset X $ is $open$ for each $open$ subset $ Z \subset Y$.? ." If yes, then you could easily prove the theorem I stated above.